# php - two file inputs two different folder

Tags: php, file, upload, directory

I'm here to ask (cause I've searched today tons of internet for this)

Here's the case:
got one form with some fields,
and then it have 2 inputs type="file".
The point is that I want the file A go to folder A, and the file B go to folder B.

what I tried:

this is projs_upload.php

```
$uploaddirb = '../images/projects/';
$uploaddira = '../images/projects/thumb/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddira . basename($_FILES['min_img']['name']);
$uploadimg = $uploaddirb . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['min_img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadimg);
```

this is form:

```
require("common.php"); 
if($_POST){
    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO projects ( 
            `idprojects`,
            `cat`, 
            `name`, 
            `desc`, 
            `min_img`,
            `img`,
            `ext_url` 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :idprojects,
            :cat,
            :name,
            :desc,
            :min_img,
            :img,
            :ext_url 
        ) 
    "; 
    $query_params = array(
        ':idprojects'=> "",
            ':cat' => $_POST['cat'],
            ':name' => $_POST['name'],
            ':desc' => $_POST['desc'],
            ':min_img' => $_FILES['min_img']['name'],
            ':img' => $_FILES['img']['name'],
            ':ext_url' => $_POST['exturl'] 
    );          
    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    include ("funcs/proj_uploads.php");
    header("Location: ?p=manage_projects"); 
    die("Redirecting done"); 
}
<form action="?p=manage_projects" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" placeholder="kategoria" name="cat" />
<input type="text" placeholder="nazwa projektu" name="name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="link do projektu" name="exturl" />
<textarea placeholder="opis" name="desc" />
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
<input type="file" placeholder="miniatura" name="img" />
<input type="file" placeholder="duży" name="img" />
<button type="submit" class="expand">Zapisz</button>
</form>
```

and "?p=manage_projects" refers to the form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `file input` tags are called `img`.

You should have one called `img` and one called `min_img`

So do:

```
<input type="file" placeholder="miniatura" name="min_img" />
<input type="file" placeholder="duży" name="img" />
```

instead of:

```
<input type="file" placeholder="miniatura" name="img" />
<input type="file" placeholder="duży" name="img" />
```

NB: This should be easily spotted with a `var_dump($_FILES)` in your `if($_POST)` block.

Comment: if all else fails, var_dump!

Answer (score 1):

Your `$uploaddirb` path needs to end in a `/`, otherwise files will be uploaded into `images/projects` as files `thumbsomename`:

```
$uploaddirb = '../images/projects/thumb/';
```

If this doesn't solve it for you, update your question with more information, i.e. both HTML and PHP code, do both files not work?, have you checked the directories exist and have proper permissions?

Comment: the path is fixed now, thanks for noticing, I've changed it hundred times alredy...

it still uploads one file I''ll update main post with more data